# how to detect the valuechange of the formControl using angular8 used via datetimepicker

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have a date picker calendar, wherein based on the date selection i am setting the value to the control. Here i have 2 controls, which are date fields. So based on date selection of first input 2nd input field dates has been set as min date, and by default, the 2nd input date must be set to one year from the selected date of 1st input field. So i have used blur event to set the date values. Here, i have choosed 09/09/2020 of first input and got 2nd input by default set as 09/09/2021, but i changed the date of 2nd input to 08/08/2021. And now i been to 1st date field, i havent changed anything and came out of the tab, the 2nd input got selected to 09/09/2021. Can anyone help me to sort this out. This is working like this because i have used (blur) event, and as soon as we are out from 1st input, even without changing date, it is set default to the 1st input value.

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control effectiveDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                    formControlName="effectiveDate" (blur)="focusEffectivDate('effectiveDate')" >
```

TS:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(".OnlyDate")
      .datetimepicker({ format: "L", useCurrent: false })
      .on("dp.change", e => {
        if (e.date) {
          const date = e.date.format("L");
          this.date = date;
        } else {
          this.date = null;
        }
      });
    if (!this.eoDetailsList) {
      $(".effectiveDate")
        .datetimepicker({ format: "L", useCurrent: false })
        .on("dp.change", e => {
          if (e.date) {
            const date = e.date.format("L");
            this.date = date;
          } else {
            this.date = null;
          }
        });
      $(".expirationDate").datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: "L",
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('.expirationDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        const date = e.date.format("L");
        this.date = date;
        $(".expirationDate")
          .data("DateTimePicker")
          .minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".expirationDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        if (e.date) {
          const date = e.date.format("L");
          this.date = date;
        } else {
          this.date = null;
        }
        $(".effectiveDate").data("DateTimePicker");
      });
    } else {
      $(".effectiveDate")
        .datetimepicker({ format: "L", useCurrent: false })
        .on("dp.change", e => {
          if (e.date) {
            const date = e.date.format("L");
            this.date = date;
          } else {
            this.date = null;
          }
        });
      $(".expirationDate").datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        format: "L",
        minDate: new Date(this.eoInfoForm.value.effectiveDate)
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('.expirationDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".effectiveDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        const date = e.date.format("L");
        this.date = date;
        $(".expirationDate")
          .data("DateTimePicker")
          .minDate(e.date);
      });
      $(".expirationDate").on("dp.change", e => {
        if (e.date) {
          const date = e.date.format("L");
          this.date = date;
        } else {
          this.date = null;
        }
        $(".effectiveDate").data("DateTimePicker");
      });

    }

  }

 public focusEffectivDate(event,name) {
    if (name == 'effectiveDate') {
      this.eoInfoForm.get('effectiveDate').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
      if (this.eoInfoForm.value.effectiveDate) {
        this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').enable();
        var aYearFromNow = new Date(this.eoInfoForm.value.effectiveDate);
        aYearFromNow.setFullYear(aYearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
        this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').patchValue(new DatePipe('en').transform(aYearFromNow, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
      } else {
        this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').disable();
      }
    } else if (name == 'expirationDate') {
      this.eoInfoForm.get('expirationDate').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
    } else {
      this.eoInfoForm.get('updateReceived').setValue(this.date, { emitEvent: false });
    }
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vayi3c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Since you using Jquery ,Can't you move move form patchValue logic inside date picker change event method?

Comment: Could you please help me out how this can be achieved

Comment: And also here the date from which expirationd date calendar starts can’t be selected. By default that date will be set and I’m second time date selection if I try to take up the date from which calendar started can’t be selected, it gives the previously selected date

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqhxh6

Comment: Yes i will check and update you

Comment: Thanks its working as expected. It really helped a lot, can you please post this as answer, i will vote

Comment: Np.Don't use Jquery with angular, Since you mixing Jquery with angular you getting un expected behaviour!!!!

Comment: yes but this project had bad requirement with that  kind of calendar, sometimes i feel frustrated thinking y i must use this, but thanks a lot, it really helped. Sorry to ask one more doubt

Comment: in jquery, for datetimepicker with both date and time, if i use 09092010 1:10Pm it takes date and time like 09/09/2020 1:10PM if choosed from calendar it takes 09/09/2020 01:10 PM, why is that 0 before 1 is not taken in datetimepicker?

Comment: i gave this format this.Restrictions[this.selectedIndex].datetime = dat.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A");, after date has been selected

Comment: as it is in hh:mm format it must take 0 before na